# How do i increase the length of a String to match another String only once WITHOUT Stringbuilder in java?

Tags: java

I have two strings in a method plaintext and keyword.  plaintext.length > keyword.length and I want to repeat the key until it's the same length as plaintext.

How would I be able to make them repeat only once?

I do not really know where to start but this is what I have:

The method has these parameters (String plaintext, String keyword)

```
    plaintext = plaintext.toUpperCase();
    keyword = keyword.toUpperCase();
    String bell = "";

    for(int i = 0; i <plaintext.length(); i++){

         int key = plaintext.length() / keyword.length();
         int r = plaintext.length() % keyword.length();
```

please help

Comment: So you want to repeat the key, but maximal one time? Can you give an example?

Comment: So like if Computer Science is the plain text and CORN1 is the keyword then get 
      CORN1CORN1CORN1C

Comment: Please edit your question with such information.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a StringBuilder?

Comment: @shmosel sounds like an assignment

Answer (score 0):

You already compute how often the key fits into the plaintext and the rest to.

So you only need a for loop to accumulate the key and then add the rest:

```
String plaintext = "Computer Science";
String key       = "CORN1";

int fullFits = plaintext.length() / key.length(); // How often does the key fit completely into the plaintext
int rest     = plaintext.length() % key.length(); // How many chars are left

String newKey = "";
for (int i = 0; i < fullFits; i++)
{
    newKey += key;
}

newKey += key.substring(0, rest);

System.out.println(newKey);
```

Prints: `CORN1CORN1CORN1C`